# Python line.split only splits single characters

Tags: python, split, delimiter

I have an array of strings like this:

Some Title##DD-MM-JJJJ##Some Text goes here##img1.jpg##img2.jpg
I'd like to split this string at ##. My code is the following:

```
with open("raw_news.txt", "r") as f:
    raw = []
    for line in f:
            line.strip()
            line.split('##')
            raw.append(line)
```

It doesn't work. I only get the single letters. re.split didn't do the trick, either. I'm really at a loss here, anyone knows what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that you're disregarding the return value of `split()`:

```
            raw.append(line.split('##'))
```

For example:

```
In [5]: s = "Some Title##DD-MM-JJJJ##Some Text goes here##img1.jpg##img2.jpg"

In [6]: s.split("##")
Out[6]: ['Some Title', 'DD-MM-JJJJ', 'Some Text goes here', 'img1.jpg', 'img2.jpg']
```